# Notepad++ delete lines ending with specific character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete all lines ending with |

I tried

```
.*[|;]
```

but it's not the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
.*\|$
```

This says "any character any number of times (`.*`), followed by a pipe (`\|` - you have to escape it), and then the end of a line (`$`)".

If you want to find lines ending with either `;` or `|`, use:

```
.*[\|;]$
```

You don't *have* to escape the pipe in this case, but I prefer to do so anyway.

In either case, make sure you're in "Regular expression" search mode with ". matches newline" unchecked.

Comment: That was helpful , and now what about delete lines that doesn't contains a specific symbole , I mean delete all lines that don't have email adresse , I will use @ as a caractere

Comment: @Faxsy You should probably go ahead and ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I think I have found the solution ^[^@]*$

Comment: **+1** for explaining with details.